# Imported repo doesn't update user Commits Calendar

Tags: gitlab

I've just created a new project in Gitlab and imported my repo. It appears to be working fine and has recognised the users from the repo as already existing in Gitlab, but on the individual user page nothing is shown on the Commits Calendar. Is there any way to get Gitlab to recognise the imported history properly or will it only display user activity performed within Gitlab?

Update: I've noticed that my Commits Calendar has updated correctly. I'm not sure if that's because I was the one who imported the repo but my colleague who already had a Gitlab account still has nothing in their calendar. Is it possibly because they weren't invited to be a member of the project until after I imported the repo?

Comment: I encounter exactly that same issue and I also only use only primary mail address for my users.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that currently (March 2015), the Commit Calendar:

- does not count commits which are made to forked projects nor merge actions are captured. ([issue 8931](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8931))
- does not count commits when primary email is not the same as in public key. ([issue 8871](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8871))

> For now the commit calendar only supports the primary mail address.
>   We'll have to test how the performance of the calendar behaves if it has to search for all email addresses.
>   I'll add it to my TODO list for 7.9.
>   We will work quite a bit on the calendar until the next release.

Comment: I don't think any of those are the cause. We're only using primary email addresses and none of the commits are showing up.

Comment: @parsley72 it might be an ACL (Access Control Level) issue then, like you mention in your updated question.

Comment: My colleague is a member of the project now. I was wondering if it's possible to re-run the parsing that's done when a repo is imported to get the calendars to update?